# Tables not formatting properly in Adobe InDesign CC

Tags: adobe-indesign, page-layout, formatting

I'm opening a client file that was created through a design agency in Indesign but the Tables are not formatting corectly - rather, just text boxes and nothing like the PDF the designers also sent over. Would be grateful if anyone could help with this!

How it's looking:
[image]

What it should be looking like:
[image]

Comment: Looks like missing fonts to me. Without examining the file, it *looks* like it's just paragraph text with bullets, tabs, and line feeds, and *not* an actual "table" as defined within InDesign. If the proper fonts were active, I imagine everything would fall into place.

Comment: Yeah, its a messy setup, but should work if the original fonts are linked to the artwork. It does look like the INDD file is missing the actual fonts, getting replaced with default fonts.